# Superscript reading from string

Tags: c, string, superscript

Is it possible to read superscript from string in C?

string is for example `f(x)=x²+2x`.

I want to read that power as `2` and use it in calculations.

Comment: Which code set is the string written in?  In UTF-8, the ² is U+00B2 (0xC2 0xB2) bytes; in ISO 8859-1 or 8859-15, it is a single byte, 0xB2 (the similarity is not coincidental).  There's nothing to stop you reading the character and interpreting it as 'power of 2'.  U+00B3 is superscript 3; U+00B9 is superscript 1; the characters U+2070..U+2079 are superscript digits 0-9.  Isn't in fun having so many numbers to choose from?  If you have a different code set, you have to know what you're dealing with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In UTF-8, the ² is U+00B2 (0xC2 0xB2) bytes; in ISO 8859-1 or 8859-15, it is a single byte, 0xB2 (the similarity is not coincidental). There's nothing to stop you reading the character and interpreting it as 'power of 2'. U+00B3 is superscript 3; U+00B9 is superscript 1; the characters U+2070..U+2079 are superscript digits 0-9. Isn't in fun having so many numbers to choose from? If you have a different code set, you have to know what you're dealing with. – Jonathan Leffler